# Difficulty in changing the message of progress dialog in async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have created an async task and want to change the message of progress dialog during different stages of doBackground. Here is the code:

```
public class sc extends AsyncTask<Integer,String,Void>
    {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog=new ProgressDialog(Loc.this);
            dialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) 
        {

            onProgressUpdate("Contacting server..Please wait..");
            //Do some work
            onProgressUpdate("Processing the result");
            //Do some work
            onProgressUpdate("Calculating..");
            dialog.dismiss();
            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String ui)
        {
            dialog.setMessage(ui);
        }


}
```

But the problem is that, progress dialog is only showing the first message always. Kindly help me to find a solution.

Comment: did you confirm the very **BASIC** debugging and ensure that it is actually going to the progress updated method at all?

Comment: Is this cut/paste from your code? There is a typo in the code: your 'onProgressUpdate mth is missing an 'r'

Comment: @JoxTraex: The first message is set with the help of progress update. The issue is that after that it is not taking the next message but executing other codes between the progress update calls

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) 
{
    onProgessUpdate("Contacting server..Please wait..");
    ...
}
```

Urrrm, nope, that won't work.

Try...

```
publishProgress("Contacting server..Please wait..");
```

You have to "**publish**" your progress in `doInBackground(..)` in order for `onProgressUpdate(...)` to be called.

Also don't call `dialog.dismiss()` in `doInBackground(...)` call it in `onPostExecute(...)` instead.

Comment: here when I apply **publishProgress("Contacting server..Please wait..");** then it show error: **The method publishProgress(Integer...) in the type AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void> is not applicable for the arguments (String)**

Comment: @VinitVikash : You need to have an AsyncTask with the signature of `<String,String,Void>` - it's the second parameter type which dictates what is passed to `onProgressUpdate()`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be..

```
publishProgress("Your Dialog message..");
```

not

```
onProgessUpdate("Processing the result");
```

in doInBack..()

Something like,

```
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
      publishProgress("Hello");
     return null;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(String msg) {
     dialog.setMessage(msg);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might also be that you haven't set an "initial message". If you don't set a message for your `ProgressDialog` before attempting to do so inside of `onProgressUpdate` it will not work.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setTitle("Title");
progressDialog.setMessage("Initial message needed");

public class foo extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Void> {
    ...
}
```

Also note that, if you need both a progress update and a message, you can use an Integer variable argument with one of the integers defining the amount of progress and the other defining the message as an index of a `String[]` array of messages (if the messages are known beforehand).