# Publish progress from an external class during Async Task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an async task with a `doInBackground()` method like this:

```
       protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          MyClass session = new MyClass("email", "password");
          return session.isAuthorized();
       }
```

While `MyClass`, which is in a completly different package, is something like this:

```
       private class MyClass {
                  // fields, constructors, etc
                  public Boolean isAuthorized() {
                             // some stuff
                             log("Action 1...");
                             // some stuff
                             log("Action 2...");
                             // some other stuff
                             return result;
                  }

                  public static void log(String str) {
                             // HERE I would like to publish progress in the Async Task
                             // but, until now, it's kinda like:
                             System.out.println(str);
                  }
       }
```

The question is: how can I pass log descriptions hold in the `log()` method, external even to the main Activity "container", to `publishProgress()` method? I already read this thread: [Difficulty in changing the message of progress dialog in async task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9063112/difficulty-in-changing-the-message-of-progress-dialog-in-async-task) - but it wasn't a valid source of help, since my method isn't contained in the main class `public class MainActivity extends Activity {}`.

EDIT #1 -

After some work, I realized that the only way is passing to the external class a referece to the "main" thread, and then implement there a specific method to publish progress. In such a way:

```
       public void log(String str) {
                  if (mThreadReference==null) {
                             System.out.println(str);
                  } else {
                             mThreadReference.doProgress();
                  }
       }
```

While `mThreadReference` points to this `AsyncTask`:

```
    private class MyClassTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>  {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // constructs MyClass instance with a reference and run main method
            (new MyClass("email", "password", this)).isAuthorized();
        }

        public void doProgress(String str) {
            publishProgress(str);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            // some stuff
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        }
    }
```

But, obviously, Eclipse is warning me: `The method publishProgress() is undefined for the type Activity`. How can I write a **general** and **absolute** method, in the external class, which I can use in more than one specific AsyncThread?

```
                           --> LOGs IN THE LOGIN THREAD 1
                          /
           EXTERNAL CLASS ---> LOGs IN THE LOGIN THREAD 2
                          \
                           --> LOGs IN THE LOGIN THREAD 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that the only way is importing the istance of the AsyncTask, which has to be public (not the default option!), in the main activity. With this trick, I can invoke the publishProgress method even if it's protected.

```
    // MyClass, in a different package

    import MainActivity.MyClassTask mThreadReference = null;

    // some stuff...

    public void log(String str) {
            if (mThreadReference==null) {
                    System.out.println(str);
            } else {
                    mThreadReference.doProgress("");
            }
    }
```

While this is the activity:

```
public class LoginLanding extends Activity {

    // stuff...

    public class MyClassTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>  {
            // bla bla bla, some stuff...

            public void doProgress(String str) {
                    // do something
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I faced similar problem. Previous answer helped be solve problem 50%. It was null pointer exception as mThreadReference is null.

Now you need an instance of the enclosing class in order to instantiate the inner class which is AsyncTask class. Since I had such class defined inside my fragment, what I did was below:

```
    MyFragment fm = new MyFragment();
    MyFragment.AsyncTaskClassName aTCN = fm.new AsyncTaskClassName();
```

After that you can call doProgress method the way Gianlunca has suggested.

My 2 cents !!